# docker-compose on ubntu 18.10 the input device is not a TTY error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker and docker compose in ubuntu 18.10 server, when i execute the command docker compose from terminal it is working, but when i configure a crontab to exexute a command with docker compose, i get this error :"The USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.the input device is not a TTY"

The USER error is related to an error with docker-compose.yml, juste for using ${USER}.

How can i fix the issue ?

PS: It was working normaly in ubuntu 18.04 server.

Comment: Hi, could you please correct your title to highlight the actual issue you're facing

Comment: What is the command your cron is running? To make a docker exec command a tty, use the -t flag

Answer (score 0):

> The cron daemon was designed in such a way that it does NOT execute commands within your normal shell environment. This means you cannot use bare commands in cron the way you would from the SSH shell command line. This is because the PATH environment variable is /usr/bin:/bin, and the SHELL environment variable is set to /bin/sh.

Something you can reference: [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215767107-Execution-environment-of-a-cron-job) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables).

So you may have to specify shell environment variable directly in crontab, like

```
USER=xxx
* * * * * /bin/echo ${USER}
```